# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated doesnt work for my TabBarController app

Tags: iphone, authentication, modal-dialog, dismiss, uitabview

I've seen many people post about modal view controllers and their sue but so far nothing that specifically fits my case.

I've created a TabBarController application and I wanted to load the app with a login modal view (just a basic subclass of the UIViewController).  My goal is that when the 'login' button is pressed, the modal view is dismissed.

I'm able to load the modal view, but when I go to dismiss it, nothing happens.  both the calls to display and dismiss the modal view are run from the app delegate.

I will post some of my code later if needed but I didn't have access to it at the time I wrote this, but if anything stands out from what I've just described please let me know, this problem is driving me crazy!!

Comment: does the method actually get called? you should try to call it from the modal view itself, and call it on the parent. something like self.parentViewController dismissModalViewController: called from the modal VC (when you want to dismiss it obviously) should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **dismissModalViewControllerAnimated**-method to dismiss the view.

Use `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in the IBAction.

Comment: I had the same problem with [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; This did the trick.